# How to define scope for column of subtype in table of supertype?

Tags: oracle

I use one table of supertype contains all data of supertype and subtype. But I don't know how to define scope of reference column for subtype.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PersonObj AS OBJECT(
oid integer,
id integer,
name varchar(20),
street varchar(20),
city varchar(10),
state varchar(20),
zipcode varchar(5),
birthDate date,
kidNames set_kids,
picture varchar(100),
place LocationAdt
) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE StudentObj UNDER PersonObj (
studentId varchar(10),
major REF DepartmentObj,
advisor REF ProfessorObj,
hasTaken set_ref_enrolledobj);
/
```

I want to define scope like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person OF personobj (id PRIMARY KEY,
major SCOPE IS department, 
advisor SCOPE IS professor) 
OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY 
NESTED TABLE kidNames STORE AS student_kidnames, 
NESTED TABLE hastaken STORE AS student_hastaken;
```

But it return error ORA-00904: "MAJOR": invalid identifier.

How to describe scope for reference column of subtype in supertype table?
Table department and professor was created.

More infomation:

```
CREATE TABLE student OF studentobj (id PRIMARY KEY,
major SCOPE IS department, 
advisor SCOPE IS professor) 
OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY 
NESTED TABLE kidNames STORE AS student_kidnames, 
NESTED TABLE hastaken STORE AS student_hastaken;
```

The above command is success.

Thanks for any information.